# compile and run java method from another class

Tags: java, compilation

**Edit:**
I read the similar Question, but its not working here. I have to check assignments for students. To the assignments have the same name(Ex2.java),they are in different directories. I want my test file to run all the assignments without having to go through each assignment separately.

I tried to compile and run function from another class. But there is no main there.

Lets say that I have this class without main:

```
public class A {

     public static int num(int x) {
           return x;
     }
}
```

The main class:

```
public class B {  
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac A.java");
         Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java A");

    }  
}
```

Now I want that class B compile and run class A.
Try to write something like this in class B:

```
A.num(x);
```

Comment: Why o why do you need to do that?

Comment: Why not just import A and then something like `int y = A.num(x)` ?

Comment: Doesn't a simple import solve your problem? If not, why not?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry I did not make myself clear enough. @NicholasK
I have to check assignments for students.
To the assignments have the same name(Ex2.java). 
I want my test file to run all the assignments without having to go through each assignment separately.

Answer (score 0):

Since all files have the same name, I assume they are in different directories, right? Try making a generic test file and create a routine to create a copy of this file in each directory, then execute each of your test files, instead of the assigments.

Comment: Sorry, I think that I dont know how to do this.. I read the similar questions but there solution not working to me.